# Use function in join

Tags: sql-server, function

Is this possible to use function in Join. 
**Why i want this**
Because my function return value from table where the data in comma separated

```
Example - '20122200',20122',
```

Return from function

```
20122200 
20122





 select FileNamePath,ex.ExprtINI,PROCESSED  from OrderExports OE
 INNER JOIN ExporterFiles EX ON EX.RefVal= CAST (OE.ID  as varchar)
 where    
  EX.ExportName = 'Ensenda'
```

in above sql statement i want to use function at `EX.RefVal= CAST (OE.ID  as varchar)` to `EX.RefVal= fngetAllRefValfromExporterFiles()`
. i tried to do this but can't do. So can you please help me about this.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from using a function in the `ON` clause AFAIK.

Comment: You are missing the 'AND' after the cast. Should be ON EX.RefVal= CAST (OE.ID  as varchar) and EX.ExportName = 'Ensenda'

Comment: @MarcusH sorry i did mistake in write

Comment: Your function has any input ?

Comment: @Prdp No not any input to my function

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `table valued function` you cannot use it like that.

Use the `TVF` result in `IN` clause

```
EX.RefVal in (select fun_col from fngetAllRefValfromExporterFiles())
```

or you can join the function with your table

```
yourtable EX
 JOIN Fngetallrefvalfromexporterfiles() b
   ON EX.RefVal = b.fun_col
```

Comment: thanks can you please tell me how i will add this in your above sql statement   INNER JOIN ExporterFiles EX  because i stuck on ON EX.Refval

Comment: @A.Goutam - How `OrderExports` & `ExporterFiles` should be joined because it is missing in your query.. Say that will post you full query

Comment: @A.Goutam - I asked you something How OrderExports & ExporterFiles should be joined ?

Comment: The ExporterFiles  will be join with function because function contained the value OrderExports table id value